# Calculate SUM with cap and multiply pro-rata by coefficient in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, teradata-sql-assistant

I have table that more or less looks like this:

```
+--------+---------------------+--------+------+
| CustId |      TransDate      | Amount | Coef |
+--------+---------------------+--------+------+
|      1 | 2020-09-04 11:02:00 |    400 |  0.1 |
|      1 | 2020-09-04 12:05:00 |    500 |  0.2 |
|      1 | 2020-09-04 13:02:00 |    400 |  0.1 |
|      1 | 2020-09-04 13:11:00 |    600 |  0.4 |
|      2 | 2020-09-04 10:01:00 |    300 |  0.3 |
|      2 | 2020-09-04 11:02:00 |    700 |  0.2 |
+--------+---------------------+--------+------+
```

What I am trying to achieve is to give each customer a "bonus" that is calculated as Amount * Coef, but with a cap of 1,500 on the total amount of transactions. The "bonus" is awarded for customers' transactions for which the SUM is <1,500 (in the order in which the transactions were made).

For example, customer "1" will receive full bonus for the first 3 transactions and a bonus for the difference to 1,500 for the 4th transaction. Basically, the end result should look like this:

```
+--------+---------------------+--------+------+---------------------------------------------------+
| CustId |      TransDate      | Amount | Coef |                       Bonus                       |
+--------+---------------------+--------+------+---------------------------------------------------+
|      1 | 2020-09-04 11:02:00 |    400 |  0.1 | 40                                                |
|      1 | 2020-09-04 12:05:00 |    500 |  0.2 | 100                                               |
|      1 | 2020-09-04 13:02:00 |    400 |  0.1 | 40                                                |
|      1 | 2020-09-04 13:11:00 |    600 |  0.4 | 80 /*(this is given only for the remaining 200)*/ |
|      2 | 2020-09-04 10:01:00 |    300 |  0.3 | 90                                                |
|      2 | 2020-09-04 11:02:00 |    700 |  0.2 | 140                                               |
+--------+---------------------+--------+------+---------------------------------------------------+
```

Thanks in advance!

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want a cumulative sum and some logic:

```
select t.*,
       (case when sum(amount) over (partition by custid order by transdate) <= 1500
             then coef * amount
             when sum(amount) over (partition by custid order by transdate) - amount < 1500
             then (1500 - sum(amount) over (partition by custid order by transdate)) as coef
             else 0
        end) as bonus
from t
```

Answer (score 0):

[EDIT]: This now caps the bonus amount using a MAX function.

Data

```
drop table if exists #tTEST;
go
select * INTO #tTEST from (values 
(1, '2020-09-04 11:02:00', 400, 0.1),
(1, '2020-09-04 12:05:00', 500, 0.2),
(1, '2020-09-04 13:02:00', 400, 0.1),
(1, '2020-09-04 13:11:00', 600, 0.4),
(1, '2020-09-05 13:11:00', 600, 0.4),
(2, '2020-09-04 10:01:00', 300, 0.3),
(3, '2020-09-04 11:02:00', 700, 0.2)) V(CustId, TransDate, Amount, Coef);
```

Query

```
declare @bonus_limit            int=1500;

with data_cte as (
    select *, sum(amount) over (partition by custid order by transdate) cum_amount,
            @bonus_limit-sum(amount) over (partition by custid order by transdate) cum_amount_diff
    from #tTEST t) 
select *, 
       (SELECT Max(v)  FROM (VALUES (0), (case when cum_amount_diff<0 then (Amount+cum_amount_diff)*Coef
                    else Amount*Coef end)) AS value(v)) Bonus
from data_cte;
```

Results

```
+--------+---------------------+--------+------+------------+-----------------+-------+
| CustId |      TransDate      | Amount | Coef | cum_amount | cum_amount_diff | Bonus |
+--------+---------------------+--------+------+------------+-----------------+-------+
|      1 | 2020-09-04 11:02:00 |    400 |  0.1 |        400 |            1100 |  40.0 |
|      1 | 2020-09-04 12:05:00 |    500 |  0.2 |        900 |             600 | 100.0 |
|      1 | 2020-09-04 13:02:00 |    400 |  0.1 |       1300 |             200 |  40.0 |
|      1 | 2020-09-04 13:11:00 |    600 |  0.4 |       1900 |            -400 |  80.0 |
|      1 | 2020-09-05 13:11:00 |    600 |  0.4 |       2500 |           -1000 |   0.0 |
|      2 | 2020-09-04 10:01:00 |    300 |  0.3 |        300 |            1200 |  90.0 |
|      3 | 2020-09-04 11:02:00 |    700 |  0.2 |        700 |             800 | 140.0 |
+--------+---------------------+--------+------+------------+-----------------+-------+
```